# How to make a python request to deepL API?

Tags: python, request, translation, deepl

I'm trying to make a python script for making translations with the DeepL API. I've tried to make a request but it responses a HTTP error 400 (Bad request).

Here is the code of my script where I replaced the real authentication key with `XXX`:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.deepl.com"

auth_key = {
    'host' : "https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?",
    'auth_key':"auth_key=XXX"
}

querystring = {
    "text" : "Che bellissima giornata",
    "target_lang" : "en"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=auth_key, data=querystring)

print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: [DeepL Python Library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python)

I was unaware of this before, but DeepL has a python package that can be used to make text and document translations far more easily than through the `requests` package. Some of this is recycled from the DeepL documentation, but updated to answer your question.

First, run a simple `pip install deepl`.

If you don't care about hard coding your auth_key, you can set it up like so:

```
import deepl

translator = deepl.Translator("auth_key")
```

To translate a single string you can do this:

```
import deepl

result = translator.translate_text("Che bellissima giornata", target_lang="EN-US")
print(result)
```

You can now also pass multiple strings in a DeepL request by putting the strings in a list:

```
import deepl

result = translator.translate_text(["お元気ですか？", "Che bellissima giornata"], target_lang="EN-US")
print(result[0].text)  # "How are you?"
print(result[0].detected_source_lang)  # "JA"
print(result[1].text)  # "What a beautiful day"
print(result[1].detected_source_lang)  # "IT"
```

If you have full foreign language documents you would like to translate you can make a request using the DeepL package as well:

```
translator.translate_document_from_filepath(
    "path/to/write/to/WhatABeautifulDay.docx", # Translated File
    "path/to/original/CheBellissimaGiornata.docx", # Original File
    target_lang="EN-US"
)
```

Just as a side note, the DeepL "EN" option is deprecated, and you must now use "EN-US" or "EN-GB" in your request.

---

OUTDATED (Still Works for Text)

In order to get a correct response, you need to structure your query as such:

```
import requests
r = requests.post(
                url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate",
                data={
                    "target_lang": "EN",
                    "auth_key": auth_key,
                    "text": string_to_translate,
                },
            )
```

Where `auth_key` is your authentication key and `string_to_translate` is the text you want to translate.

I formatted the above code using [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/), which is why it looks different than what [dwightkschruteIII](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11660098/dwightkschruteiii) included, though it is essentially doing the same thing.

To access this translation using python, however, you need to use the following code:

`r.json()["translations"][0]["text"]`

Because DeepL will return a json with `translations` as its only key, with a list containing another json as the corresponding value. The json within the list has two keys: `detected_source_language` and `text`. This was a verbose explanation, so I've provided a sample below:

The commands:

```
sample = requests.post(url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate", data={"target_lang": "EN", "auth_key": auth_key, "text": "Che bellissima giornata"})

print(sample.json())
```

Return:

```
{'translations': [{'detected_source_language': 'IT', 'text': 'What a beautiful day'}]}
```

So to reiterate, you must use `sample.json()["translations"][0]["text"]` to access the translation, where sample is whatever you named your response, and the first code block to get a successful request.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases it is necessary to write a POST request, then you should proceed as follows (also from the DeepL FAQs):

> How can I avoid error 414, "Request-URI Too Long"?
> This error occurs if the API URLs are too long and is due to a length limit of the web server. You can avoid this error message by using a POST request instead of a GET request.

Therefore you can use the requests package as follows:

```
import requests

r =  requests.post(url='https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate',
                          data = {
                            'target_lang' : 'EN',  
                            'auth_key' : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                            'text': 'Was ist denn los hier?'
                          })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the credentials, `text` and `target_lang` as parameters to the url, like:

```
https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=&text=Che%20bellissima%20giornata&source_lang=IT&target_lang=EN
```

DeepL provides a tool for creating example requests: See *How can I create URL examples for API requests?* on https://www.deepl.com/pro-faq.html

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2021, DeepL also offers an open source Python client library for its API: https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python.

Below is an example request from the README. You'll need to `pip install --upgrade deepl` first (here's the project in PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/deepl/).

```
import deepl

# Create a Translator object providing your DeepL API authentication key
translator = deepl.Translator("YOUR_AUTH_KEY")

# Translate text into a target language, in this case, French
result = translator.translate_text("Hello, world!", target_lang="FR")
print(result) # "Bonjour, le monde !"
```

Comment: Good to know, however I get an error while trying to using it. I opened an issue on their Github, I hope they will answer quickly.

Comment: @SilentCloud thanks for sharing, did you get a response from them / is it working for you now?

Comment: Yes, the API key I was using is not compatible with the API usage, but only with CAT tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os    
import deepl

def translate_with_deepl(text, target_language, deepl_auth_key):
   '''translate with the (free) deepl api - you have to sign in to get 
   your authentication key'''

   translator = deepl.Translator(deepl_auth_key)
   return translator.translate_text(text, target_lang=target_language)

text = '你好'
target_language = 'EN-GB'
deepl_auth_key = os.environ.get('DEEPL_KEY') #your key in env-variables


print(translate_with_deepl(text, target_language, deepl_auth_key))
# Hello
```